# How to use an external Jar file in the Hadoop program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a Hadoop program in which I use a couple of external jar files. When I submit the jar file of my program to the Hadoop cluster it gives me the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/Graph
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:201)
```

I understand what the problem is but don't know how to solve it. How can I add the jar files to my program?

Comment: How u run your jar file? Is it from remote machine or using hapoop's jar command on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can also modify the environment of the job’s running task attempts explicitly by specifying JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables:

hadoop jar  [main class]
      -D mapred.child.env="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/libs" ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIBJARS option when submitting the jobs like this:

```
export LIBJARS=/path/jar1,/path/jar2
hadoop jar my-example.jar com.example.MyTool -libjars ${LIBJARS} -mytoolopt value
```

I would recommend reading this article which describes precisely what you're looking for, in detail:
http://grepalex.com/2013/02/25/hadoop-libjars/

Answer (score 0):

Add external jar file into the hadoop/lib folder to get rid out of it...